# Get choice django with post request

Tags: python, django

I have found many solutions to get choice in Django field but they work when using a template
such as `get_foo_display`

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
```

But what I have to do if I need to get Male or Female with `request.POST` in views.py.
Currently I am using `request.POST['gender']` But this is giving me M or F

Comment: If you need the full word, then put that in the choices: `('Male', 'Male'),`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change `M` to `Male` and `F` to `Female` in the `CATEGORY_CHOICES`. The first term is the one that will be sent to the backend, the later one is the string the client will 'see'.

Comment: The second term is only for client-side display.  Those values are not submitted as part of them form.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a choice, I would do something like this,

```
choice_dict = {
    "M": "Male",
    "F": "Female"
}
CATEGORY_CHOICES = ((k, v) for k, v in choice_dict.items())
```

Then in views,

```
actual_value = choice_dict[request.POST['gender']]
```